# Trying to write SQL Self Join?

Tags: sql, self-join

I have a user table associated to a website with when customers forget there password they create a new account rather then be bothered retrieving their forgotten password.

I would like to see how many times a customer may have joined the website by joining the user table to itself using the customer email address and the ID would be unique each time they joined and I put a statement in checking to see if the Account IDs are different.

Here is my query:

```
`Select Distinct
T1.Email as "eMail-01", T2.Email as "eMail-02", T1.AccountID as "AccountID-01",     T2.AccountID as "AccountID-02", T1.UserID as "UserID-01", T2.UserID as "UserID-02"

From User T1
Left Join Users T2 on T1.eMail = T2.eMail

Where ( T2.eMail is not null ) and ( T2.eMail <> '' ) 
and ( T1.AccountID <> T2.AccountID )`
```

The table has about 60,000 records in it and I seem to be getting a great number records returned base on the number of AccountID permeations.

For instance 1 Customer registered 5 times with the same email address, so I’m getting 25 records back (5 x 5).  I’m not sure if I’m writing this query correctly.

The query is running very long.

Comment: Which rdmbs are you using?

Comment: By the way, dooing a left join with where ? is not null is the same as an inner join and should be better optimized by your rdbms

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you most probably want is a count of AccountID per email address so there's no need for self join here. The query would be :

```
SELECT Email, count(AccountID)
FROM User
GROUP BY Email
```

and should run quite quickly event with 60.000 emails.

Anyway, you should think about putting a UNIQUE index on the email column after cleaning the table. You could then benefit with email search performances and prevent users to create multiple account with the same e-mail address. This should help them retrieve their password instead.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

First, you are using a `left join` which is useless, because you filter the records that are not null on the right side of the relation (which can be acomplished with a simple `inner join`). Either you use `inner join` or remove the condition `T2.eMail is not null`.

Secondly, is your table properly indexed? If it is not, add the appropriate indexes.

Thirdly, you can use a very simple query to track down the emails that have more than one `accountId`:

```
select email, count(accountId) as accounts
from user
group by email
having count(accountId) > 1
```

Then you can work using only the emails that have more than one account.

Hope this helps